# Sticky Table Header jumps when link in Table Body is clicked

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have a basic css table with a sticky header. For the most part the header works as intended but if I scroll through my entries and then click one of the download links in the table the header moves down the page by the amount I scrolled before I clicked the link, usually this results in the header disappearing.
Code is as follows (edited for brevity):

**HTML**

```
<table id="viewall" style="table-layout:auto; width: auto;" class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Download Links </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                                                 
    <tbody>   

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" })

    </tbody>                                                
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#viewall 
    width: 100%;
    height: 770px;
    display: block;
    margin-right:3%;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: auto; /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}

#pdf {
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}

thead tr th {
    background: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; 
}

tbody {
    display:table-row-group;
}
```

I had a similar problem with popover warning labels but that was easily solved by changing the position CSS to fixed for some reason. This fix doesn't work on the links.

**EDIT**

This problem only occurs in Chrome/Firefox.

***EXAMPLE:**

```
    <table id="viewall" style="table-layout:auto; width: auto;" class="table table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="th0">
                        SelectAll<br />
                        <center><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll(this)" /></center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        PDF
                    </th>
                    <th id="th21" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        Time
                    </th>

                    <th id="th3">
                        Action
                    </th>
     </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
<tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
<tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
<tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
<tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
<tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
<tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
<tr>
                       <th>
                       <center>@Html.CheckBox()</center>                     
                       </th>                                                  
                       <td>                                     
                       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DownloadPDF", new { emailID, attachmentID, fileName }, new { @id = "pdf", @class = "far fa-file-pdf fa-3x" }) 
                       </td>                                                    
                    <td headers="th21"> 11/11/11 </td>
                    <td headers="th3"> Buy
                    </tr> 
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, your css is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: yeah I had noticed that but adding the bracket seems to mess some other stuff up. I even used the inspector to see where it was auto playing the bracket, then editing it to be the same but that didn't work. EDIT: fixed the bracket problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue (which is a Chrome bug) add the following line to your header:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

```css
#viewall {
  width: 100%;
  height: 770px;
  display: block;
  margin-right:3%;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
  overflow-x: auto; /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}

thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

thead tr th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; 
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

tbody {
  display:table-row-group;
}

#pdf {
  color:black;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="viewall" style="table-layout:auto; width: auto;" class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Download Links </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>                                                 
  <tbody> 
  <tr>                                                 
    <td>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </td>    
  </tr>
  </tbody>                                                
</table>
```

Comment: @SigynOdinson: Workaround you might be able to use: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly36csxn/25/ Instead of sticky header make the table body a fixed height - but this is dependant on what other styles you use.

Comment: That fix does keep the heading in place, but it stacks all of my table headings and table contents vertically in an unreadable  format that I am unable to fix.

Comment: Can you make an example with your table data?

Comment: Added an example to my original post

Comment: Fix didn't work. But I reimplemented the table from scratch using datatable with the fixed header plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Replace table with an implementation that uses datatables making use of the fixed-header plugin.